# How to create a sidebar in my Google Workspace add-on for Google Sheets by using the appsscript.json file?

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, v8, google-workspace

I'm trying to create a sidebar in my Google Sheets app by using the appsscript.json file.

[I'm trying to figure out how to use this tool](https://gw-card-builder.web.app) and the JSON file it generates.

[Also the documentation here.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/)

I get the following error:

> "appsscript.json" has errors: Invalid manifest: unknown fields: [sidebar].

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Does Google Apps Script runtime even support the creation of sidebars in Google Sheets using the appsscript.json file?

###### appsscript.json

```json
{
  "timeZone": "America/New_York",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"
  ],
  "sidebar": {
    "name": "My Sidebar Add-on",
    "iconUrl": "https://path/to/icon.png",
    "url": "https://path/to/sidebar.html"
  }
}
```

Comment: What make you think that you could modify the manifest that way? Have you read the docs?  Start by reading https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs.

Comment: Or maybe you should start to clarify if what do you mean by "Google Sheets  app" (Good docs used Editor add-on and Workspace add-on) Ref. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/types

Comment: @Rubén: I'm trying to figure out how to use this tool... https://gw-card-builder.web.app/ ... and the JSON file it generates.

Comment: @Rubén: and also the documentation here... https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/card-interfaces

Comment: I'm sorry. I haven't used that tool, but as it designs Cards the JSON that it generates can't be used in Google Apps Script, that it's intended to be used when building add-ons using other runtimes. See https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/overview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Google Apps Script doesn't support the creation of sidebars in Google Sheets using the appsscript.json file.

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/manifests
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/manifest

---

There are two types of "sidebars" one that requires the use of HTML Service and another that requires the use of the Card Service. The first corresponds to Editors Add-ons, the second to Workspace Add-ons.

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/types

To create sidebars using JSON that is possible for Workspace Add-ons but that implies the use of another runtime.

- https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/overview